# Cmake: is correct this syntax for mandir,sysconfdir,etc?

Tags: cmake

On classic configure linux I use

```
./configure --mandir=/usr/man \
--sysconfdir=/etc \
--localstatedir=/var
```

How to convert it to cmake?

I tried..

```
cmake \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_MANDIR=/usr/man \
```

But don't work still wrote manpages on usr/share/man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common convention is to use `CMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR`, but that's just a convention.  The actual name used is whatever the author of the program you want to install chose to call it.